# Ошибка в Python при вводе (команда input)

Tags: python, input

Код:

```
number = 100
running = True

while running:
    guess = (int(input('Введите целое число: ')))

    if guess == number:
        print('Вы выбрали число {}'.format(guess))
        print('Проверяем введенное вами число... \
    Поздравляем, вы угадали!')
        break
    elif guess < number:
        print('Вы выбрали число {}'.format(guess))
        print('Проверяем введенное вами число... \
    Оно меньше, чем нужно. Попробуйте еще раз.')
        continue
    else:
        print('Вы выбрали число {}'.format(guess))
        print('Проверяем введенное вами число... \
    Оно больше, чем нужно. Попробуйте еще раз.')
        continue
print('На этом наши полномочия все')
```

Командная строка и терминал в PyCharm работают правильно:

```
C:\Python\PyCharm>python 10.py
Введите целое число: 56
Вы выбрали число 56
Проверяем введенное вами число... Оно меньше, чем нужно. Попробуйте еще раз.
Введите целое число:
```

При запуске через программу ошибку не выдает, но работает некорректно:

```
C:\Python\python.exe C:/Python/PyCharm/10.py
‚ўҐ¤ЁвҐ жҐ«®Ґ зЁб«®:
```

Число ввести можно, но при его вводе оно не отображается. После того как нажимаю Enter программа выдает следующее:

```
C:\Python\python.exe C:/Python/PyCharm/10.py
‚ўҐ¤ЁвҐ жҐ«®Ґ зЁб«®:Вы выбрали число 45
Проверяем введенное вами число... Оно меньше, чем ‚ўҐ¤ЁвҐ жҐ«®Ґ зЁб«®: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/PyCharm/10.py",  нужно. Попробуйте еще раз.
line 5, in <module>
    guess = (int(input('‚ўҐ¤ЁвҐ жҐ«®Ґ зЁб«®: ')))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Другие коды работают нормально, но если присутствует команда input программа начинает лагать. Как это исправить?

Comment: А в какой кодировке сохранён код?

Comment: @nomnoms12
    sys.getdefaultencoding()
    'utf-8'
    locale.getpreferredencoding()
    'cp1251'
    sys.stdout.encoding
    'UTF-8'

Comment: Судя по ошибке, вы добавили «пустое» место, т.е. слишком рано нажали enter, попробуйте ещё раз...или же попробуйте онлайн компилятор

Comment: @JackWolf Конкретно этот код в онлайн-компиляторе работает, но другой (с созданием zip-файла) нет, т.к. компилятор не может найти каталоги на моем компе. А Enter я нажимаю после ввода числа, не догоняю, что значит рано

Comment: Ошибка указывает на то, что у вас где-то затесалась пустота, может, такое поведение связано с путём к файлу... или можно попробовать поменять тип данных на string, тогда number = ‘100‘ и guess = input('Введите целое число:\t')